# Forward DNS local to Jira URL

Tags: windows-server-2016, internal-dns, cname-record, jira, helpdesk

I want to redirect my old helpdesk domain Help.company.com to Jira URL ( Company.atlassian.net/Jira/Helpdesk), it's a simple forwarding and don't want to keep the old URL .

I tried to do a CNAME but it didn't work .
I have an AD DNS and external DNS provider Dyn.
your help is really appreciated

Comment: DNS never does any forwarding. You need a specific configuration of web server (who'll do *redirect* to the correct URL) and DNS should point to that web server.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is not only a DNS, but actual URLs you need a webserver that does 301 (permanent) redirects. (You can not solve this with DNS only)

if it only was `help.company.com` that should go to `company.atlassian.net` *AND* you could setup Atlassian to listen to that hostname, then you could do it with CNAME, but that is not the case here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer , it doesn't matter if it's URL , company.atlassian.net can do the job , when you mention CNAME you mean AD DNS or external DNS and how I can Atlassian listen to that hostname . sorry DNS is not my strength at all .

Comment: What you want to do will not be resolved with DNS.

Comment: Do you how it can be done ?

Comment: Running a webserver that does redirects (is included in the answer)